# How to update minikube latest version?

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, minikube

When I command minikube status it shows but with a GitHub link says that update minikube. Can you tell me how can I do this in a simple way?

```
$ minikube status
⚠️  There is a newer version of minikube available (v1.3.1).  Download it here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/tag/v1.3.1

To disable this notification, run the following:
minikube config set WantUpdateNotification false

host: Stopped
kubelet: 
apiserver: 
kubectl:
```

Comment: FYI - `minikube update-check` this command shows, your current installed version and latest available version.

Answer (score 44):

The script below **removes everything** (pods, services, *secrets*, etc.) that are found in Minikube, deletes old Minikube file, **install latest Minikube** file and then **enables** `ingress` and `dashboard` addons.

```
#! /bin/sh

# Minikube update script file

minikube delete && \ 
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/minikube && \ 
sudo curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64 && \ 
sudo chmod +x minikube && \ 
sudo cp minikube /usr/local/bin/ && \ 
sudo rm minikube && \  
minikube start &&\

# Enabling addons: ingress, dashboard
minikube addons enable ingress && \
minikube addons enable dashboard && \
minikube addons enable metrics-server && \
# Showing enabled addons
echo '\n\n\033[4;33m Enabled Addons \033[0m' && \
minikube addons list | grep STATUS && minikube addons list | grep enabled && \

# Showing current status of Minikube
echo '\n\n\033[4;33m Current status of Minikube \033[0m' && minikube status
```

(To make use of `dashboard` addons, execute the command of `minikube dashboard` on the terminal)

Sample terminal output after script run:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for auto-update script, I edited on `minikube start` command with added option `----container-runtime='containerd'` as it needed on rootless mode on my local setup.

Answer (score 10):

While updating for my Ubuntu 18.04 I did following

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube_latest_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i minikube_latest_amd64.deb
minikube version # to check the version
minikube start # start minikube
minikube addons list # then check addons
```

For linux it saves it states at home `.minikube` directory so no need to delete previous minikube and then enabling addons it will automatically pick the addons and enable once it read states from `.minikube` directory.

Comment: above commands upgrage your minikube CLI version, and once you run command - `minikube start --driver=virtualbox/docker`, it will download minikube current updated version ISO image, and works fine.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer :) Works great.

Comment: This works; you do not need to delete everything from minikube in order to upgrade it.  However, it should be noted that this will not upgrade the version of Kubernetes running on pre-existing minikube clusters ("profiles" in minikube), which can be shown with `minikube profile list`

Answer (score 6):

```
$ sudo minikube delete
$ curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/v1.3.1/minikube-linux-amd64 && chmod +x minikube && sudo cp minikube /usr/local/bin/ && rm minikube
$ sudo minikube start --vm-driver=none
```

Comment: Prefix a line with 4 spaces to make it look like code, and not like text.

Comment: i followd your way but after following my minikube is crashed so can u please help me?

Comment: $ minikube status

  Error getting bootstrapper: getting kubeadm bootstrapper: command runner: getting ssh client for bootstrapper: Error dialing tcp via ssh client: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:22: connect: connection refused

  Sorry that minikube crashed. If this was unexpected, we would love to hear from you:
  https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose

Comment: $ minikube status

  Error getting bootstrapper: getting kubeadm bootstrapper: command runner: getting ssh client for bootstrapper: Error dialing tcp via ssh client: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:22: connect: connection refused

  Sorry that minikube crashed. If this was unexpected, we would love to hear from you:
  https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose

Comment: $ minikube status        Error getting bootstrapper: getting kubeadm bootstrapper: command runner: getting ssh client for bootstrapper: Error dialing tcp via ssh client: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:22: connect: connection refused                   Sorry that minikube crashed. If this was unexpected, we would love to hear from you:  github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose

Comment: i put spaces but it remove.

Comment: its easy to uinderstand the gernade emoji i 1st line then the seond line started from the cat emoji.           and seond thimg is that sometimes error comes to says that error starting a new host

Comment: @Muhammad, Question was how to upgrade minikube version. Answer is correctly. If you have issue with start minikube you should create new question with more data. Docker, minikube, kubeadm version, which platform, etc.

Comment: Hey @MuhammadQasimQadri try this to resolve that error : 
$ minikube stop    
$ minikube delete    
$ rm -rf ~/.minikube/  
$ rm -rf  ~/.kube/ 

and then run 

$ minikube start

Answer (score 4):

For those running mk on windows, follow these steps : (you will get the latest version of mk)

```
1: minikube stop
2: choco upgrade minikube
3: visit https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases --> see latest version of kubernetes supported.
4: minikube start --kubernetes-version=1.xx.x
5: choco upgrade kubernetes-cli
6: kubectl version : to verify the update
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I found running `minikube delete` doesn't actually delete binary  /usr/local/bin/minikube. Either delete it manually or you need to copy latest minikube into /usr/local/bin manually