# Kubernetes is not assigning address to ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am a beginner with k8s and I followed the [k8s official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/) to create a hello-world ingress, but I can't make it work. First I create a service and just like the tutorial I get:

```
$ kubectl get service web 

NAME   TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
web    NodePort   10.100.208.38   <none>        8080:31921/TCP   19m
```

so, I can access my service via browser:

```
$ minikube service web

Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: web-79d88c97d6-xrshs
```

So far so good. However, I get stuck in the ingress part. So I create this ingress like the [tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/):

```
$ kubectl describe ingress example-ingress

Name:             example-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend"  not found>)
Rules:
Host              Path  Backends
----              ----  --------
hello-world.info  
                /   web:8080 (172.17.0.4:8080)
Annotations:        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
...
```

and even after configuring /etc/hosts with my minikube ip: 192.168.99.102  hello-world.info, when I curl it or access by the browser I get nginx 404. It's strange that my ingress does not get an address, even after a while. Can anyone point me where the error is ?

PS. I did my research before asking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51511547/empty-address-kubernetes-ingress). I check that my minikube ingress addon is enabled and my ingress-nginx-controller pod is running.

PS2. My minikube version is 1.23 and my kubectl client and server versions are 1.22.1.

Comment: Are you able to show the ingress controller pod logs?

Comment: ... Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work
... "Ignoring ingress because of error while validating ingress class" ingress="default/example-ingress" error="ingress does not contain a valid IngressClass"
... Failed to update lock: configmaps "ingress-controller-leader" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:ingress-nginx:ingress-nginx" cannot update resource "configmaps" in API group "" in the namespace "ingress-nginx"

Comment: Can you also do ```kubectl get ingressclass -A```?

Comment: kubectl get ingressclass -A: "No resources found"

Comment: Is it Minikube 1.23.0 you are running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems there is a bug with the Ingress Addon with Minikube 1.23.0, as documented [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/12445), which matches the issue you are seeing. ConfigMap issues prevent IngressClass from being generated (usually "nginx" by default) and ingress services won't work.

This issue was [fixed in 1.23.1](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/tag/v1.23.1), so updating Minikube should fix your issue.

Comment: indeed, there was an issue with the Minikube 1.23.0, and after upgrading the issue was solved. For those who have the same doubt, I followed the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57821066/how-to-update-minikube-latest-version